# OpenGL Programmable Pipeline runs slower?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, shader

Is it possible for fixed pipeline to run faster than programmable pipeline on some graphic cards ? i'm currently developing a program in C++/C# (pure OpenGL embedded in WPF as dll control) and i was comparing the rendering time for simple cubes with texture on them, nothing more..

example results:
60 000 vertices FFP: 26 FPS   / PSP: 19
40 000 vertices FFP: 50 FPS   / PSP: 28
20 000 vertices FFP: 88 FPS   / PSP: 50
..
500 vertices FFP: 520 FPS / PSP: 520

vertes shader:

```
 gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
 gl_Position = ftransform();
 gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

fragment:

```
 vec4 color = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
 gl_FragColor = color;
```

I develop this on Win 7 but on Mac-mini machine (with windows 7 installed on one of the partitions). Is it possible this is affecting the performance ? As soon as i have a chance i'll test this on different machine but ... working environment.. not possible now.

Comment: What do you mean by CPU and GPU?

Comment: what does this mean: "CPU: 26 FPS / GPU: 19" do you treat fixed pipeline as a "CPU" and "programmable pipeline" as "GPU" ?

Comment: Yes, whatever you call this... by GPU i  mean using shaders, by CPU not using shaders... sorry for confusion.

Comment: @PawelKlapuch: Call is FFP (Fixed Function Pipeline) / PSP (Programmable Shader Pipeline) then.

Answer (score 2):

Just asking the default question when it comes to Windows 7: Did you download and install the drivers from the GPU vendor website, or do you just use the default drivers shipping with Windows?

You should always use GPU drivers distributed by the GPU vendor and *not* use the ones shipping with Windows.

Comment: well i did update, so it says that it's the current driver and opengl version is stated as 3.1.0...

Comment: @PawelKlapuch: When you say "Update" Windows Update, or actual download from the vendor website. This is important, because the drivers obtained through Windows built in methods are usually crippled. However OpenGL-3.1.0 suggest you got a proper driver installed. What kind of GPU does your system have?